# Visual studio + cmake + WSL2: how to execute tasks from tasks.vs.json inside WSL

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, wsl-2

I have project CMake project targeting linux under Visual Studio 2022 (NOT VS Code).
Using CMakePresets.json i can build and debug using WSL.

But I cannot find how to use tasks.vs.json file to add tasks that would execute under WSL.
VS seems to execute tasks under Windows.

I have tried to use the "remote" task type but I don't know how to target the WSL machine.

**UPDATE**
I have found a solution using the wsl.exe command line option "--" and the WSLENV environment variable.

```
 {
  "taskLabel": "task-test",
  "appliesTo": "/",
  "contextType": "custom",
  "type": "launch",
  "command": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
  "env": {
    "MY_TASK_VAR": "${cmake.CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}",
    "WSLENV": "USERPROFILE/up:MY_TASK_VAR/u"
  },
  "args": [
    "--",
    "printenv"
  ]
}
```

The macros that can be used seems very limited, I could not reuse variables defined in the CMakePresets.json file for instance.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170#variable-substitution-in--launchvsjson-and--tasksvsjson.
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#macros-for-tasksvsjson

Comment: Are you refering to Visual Studio or Visual Studio ***Code***? The json file indicates the latter... Btw: Those "tasks" sound a bit like custom targets of the cmake project...

Comment: Visual studio 2022 (not VS code). It also has support for tasks.vs.json file.

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/tasks-vs-json-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170#remote-properties)?

Comment: Thak you for the very helpful comment. Have you read the linked doc yourself ? There are no mention of WSL.

Comment: I thought they're treating WSL connections just like any other remote connection to linux environments, my bad.

Comment: Tbh I guess you could treat it like a remote Linux.  But based on what can do vs.code. I thought VS 2022 could do more.